# How to solve IllegalArgumentException in Spring security

Tags: spring-security

I'm using spring security. When I browse to `http://localhost:8080/rest/user/json/quypham`, I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] /rest/user/json/quypham java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_ADMIN'
        at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evalua
teAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:15)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter
.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:36)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter
.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(Affi
rmativeBased.java:62)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterce
ptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter

Caused by:
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
(pos 0): Property or field 'ROLE_ADMIN' cannot be found on object of
type 'org.s
pringframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
- maybe  not public?
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.read
Property(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:215)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getV
alueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getV
alueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:78)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(Sp
elNodeImpl.java:114)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(
SpelExpression.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evalua
```

I think I have something wrong in my `userservice-servlet.xml` file:

```xml
<security:http>
  <security:http-basic/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>      
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
      <security:user name="datpham" password="Dat12345" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
      <security:user name="hoaipham" password="Hoai12345" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
    </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Here is `UserRestServiceController.java`:

```java
@Controller
public class UserRestServiceController {
    @Autowired
    public  UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    public View jsonTemplate;
    @RequestMapping(value="/rest/user/json/{username}",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User loadUser(@PathVariable("username") String name){
        return userDao.loadUser(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, [expression-based access-control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web) is enabled. That means you should change `access` value to an expression:

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
```

As an *option*, you can disable expressions:

```xml
<security:http use-expressions="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

For all roles you have to use 'hasRole'.
In your case ***access="hasRole('ADMIN')"*** to be used  when <***http use-expressions="false">***

Comment: You got it backwards. Your statements are incorrect.